# How to get many-to-one id column only?

Tags: hibernate

For example I have Project entity:

```
public class Project {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private User manager;

    @Column(name = "manager_id")
    private Long managerId;

    ...
}
```

How to mapping column "manager_id" to "managerId" attribute without lazy load manager entity?

Answer (score 0):

> How to mapping column "manager_id" to "managerId"

You don't need to do it. Hibernate already has `manager.id` even for a lazy entity.

If you have a lazy property, you can get an identifier by this way:

```
LazyInitializer initializer = ((HibernateProxy) project.getManager()).getHibernateLazyInitializer();
Long managerId = (Long) initializer.getIdentifier();
```

Please, remove `private Long managerId` field from `Project`

```
public class Project {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private User manager;

}
```

You can refer for a more common approach: [Persistent#getPid()](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/test/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/test/persistent/Persistent.java#L58)